# Solr API , how to access document?

Tags: solr

I am developing custom request handler using solr api.
Well as a reference I am taking "MoreLikeThis" as reference.

I am able to access document using "getDocList" API and then taking object of "iterator" but it gives me only document Id .

how can I access each field of document ??

```
package org.apache.solr.handler.ext;

import org.apache.solr.request.*;
import org.apache.solr.response.*;
import org.apache.solr.handler.*;
import org.apache.solr.core.*;
import org.apache.solr.schema.*;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.*;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.*;
import org.apache.solr.search.*;
import org.apache.lucene.search.*;
import org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.*;

import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyRequestHandler extends RequestHandlerBase{


@Override
  public void handleRequestBody(SolrQueryRequest req, SolrQueryResponse rsp)
      throws Exception {

    System.out.println("I am in My Handler");

    /**
     *  Working with core
     */
    SolrCore core = req.getCore();
    System.out.println("Core is " + "" + core.getDescription());
    System.out.println("Data directory is " + "" + core.getDataDir());
    System.out.println("Index directory is " + "" + core.getIndexDir());


    /**
     *  Working with schema
     */
    IndexSchema schema = core.getSchema();
    SchemaField field = schema.getField("country");

    System.out.println(field.isRequired());

    /**
     *  Create Map
     */

    IndexSchema schemaObj = req.getSchema();

    Map<String , SchemaField>map = req.getSchema().getFields();

    // Iterate over keys
    for (String str : map.keySet()){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    // Iterate over SchemaField

    for (SchemaField schemaFieldObj: map.values()){

        System.out.println(schemaFieldObj.isRequired());
    }

    /**
     *  Find the Unique Key Field
     */

    field = schemaObj.getUniqueKeyField();
    System.out.println(field.getName());

    System.out.println(schemaObj.getQueryParserDefaultOperator());



    /**
     *   Working with request parameters
     */

    SolrParams reqParams = req.getParams();
    String q = reqParams.get(CommonParams.Q);
    System.out.println(reqParams.get(CommonParams.Q));

    String defType = reqParams.get(QueryParsing.DEFTYPE , QParserPlugin.DEFAULT_QTYPE);
    System.out.println(defType);


    /**
     *  Working with QParser
     */
    QParser queryParser = QParser.getParser(q, defType, req);
    Query query = queryParser.getQuery();


    /**
     *   Now get searcher 
     */

    SolrIndexSearcher indexSearcher = req.getSearcher();
    DocList matchDocs = indexSearcher.getDocList(query, null, null, 1, 100000,10000);

    // Number of documents matched
    System.out.println(matchDocs.matches());
    // Get Iterator
        // get documentreader
        Reader reader;
    IndexReader readDoc;
    Document doc;
    DocIterator iterator = matchDocs.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
    Integer id = iterator.nextDoc();
    System.out.println("Here I am " + id);


         /*   HOW TO ACCESS ALL FIELDS OF DOCUMENT */


    }

}

  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
    return "My Search Handler";
  }

  @Override
  public String getSource() {
    return "$Source$";
  }


  @Override
  public String getVersion() {
    return "$Revision$";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well I got the answer .. 
here is the code which help me to get to each field..

```
package org.apache.solr.handler.ext;


public class MyRequestHandler extends RequestHandlerBase{


@Override
  public void handleRequestBody(SolrQueryRequest req, SolrQueryResponse rsp)
      throws Exception {

    System.out.println("I am in My Handler");

    /**
     *  Working with core
     */
    SolrCore core = req.getCore();
    System.out.println("Core is " + "" + core.getDescription());
    System.out.println("Data directory is " + "" + core.getDataDir());
    System.out.println("Index directory is " + "" + core.getIndexDir());


    /**
     *  Working with schema
     */
    IndexSchema schema = core.getSchema();
    SchemaField field = schema.getField("country");

    System.out.println(field.isRequired());

    /**
     *  Create Map
     */

    IndexSchema schemaObj = req.getSchema();

    Map<String , SchemaField>map = req.getSchema().getFields();

    // Iterate over keys
    for (String str : map.keySet()){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    // Iterate over SchemaField

    for (SchemaField schemaFieldObj: map.values()){

        System.out.println(schemaFieldObj.isRequired());
    }

    /**
     *  Find the Unique Key Field
     */

    field = schemaObj.getUniqueKeyField();
    System.out.println(field.getName());

    System.out.println(schemaObj.getQueryParserDefaultOperator());



    /**
     *   Working with request parameters
     */

    SolrParams reqParams = req.getParams();
    String q = reqParams.get(CommonParams.Q);
    System.out.println(reqParams.get(CommonParams.Q));

    String defType = reqParams.get(QueryParsing.DEFTYPE , QParserPlugin.DEFAULT_QTYPE);
    System.out.println(defType);


    /**
     *  Working with QParser
     */
    QParser queryParser = QParser.getParser(q, defType, req);
    Query query = queryParser.getQuery();


    /**
     *   Now get searcher 
     */

    SolrIndexSearcher indexSearcher = req.getSearcher();
    IndexReader reader = indexSearcher.getIndexReader();
    DocList matchDocs = indexSearcher.getDocList(query, null, null, 1, 100000,10000);

    // Number of documents matched
    System.out.println(matchDocs.matches());
    // Get Iterator
        // get documentreader

    Document doc;
    String[] DocFields;

    DocIterator iterator = matchDocs.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
    Integer id = iterator.nextDoc();
    System.out.println("Here I am " + id);
    doc = reader.document(id);
    DocFields = doc.getValues("state");

    for(int i=0;i<DocFields.length;i++){
        System.out.println(DocFields[i]);
    }

    }

}

  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
    return "My Search Handler";
  }

  @Override
  public String getSource() {
    return "$Source$";
  }


  @Override
  public String getVersion() {
    return "$Revision$";
  }

}
```

Well in short, we to access document we need "reader" an object of "IndexReader" class then from 'reader' call method 'getValues(' YOUR FIELD NAME')' . It will return array of Strings.